# Is there a .net driver that supports SSL connection with verify-full to PostgreSQL?

Tags: c#, .net, postgresql, ssl, devart

I am trying to connect to a PostgreSQL database using SSL. The connection requires that SSLMode is verify-full, but the driver I use (from devart.com), supports Require as the highest level.

Is there a way to accomplish this using the latest driver from devart? If not, is there any other driver that supports this?

I am able to connect using a native ODBC driver, so the connection works for native programs, but need a .Net driver to avoid importing ODBC libraries into my .NET application.

Comment: Have you tried npgsql http://npgsql.projects.pgfoundry.org/ http://fxjr.blogspot.com.es/2010/04/using-ssl-client-certificates-with.html

Comment: No, have not tried that, but could not find anything in their documentation about SSLMode=verify-full. So looking for some definitive guidance from someone who has used this before trying another driver. The devart driver works well without SSL, and I have a license to use that, but will wait a little bit to see if anyone else has experience around this specific problem.

Comment: Yes, dotConnect for PostgreSQL supports the Require mode as the highest level. However, if you use SslMode.Require and specify the 'SSL CA Cert' connection string parameter, the behavior will be the same as with 'verify-ca' SSL mode.

Comment: There was a bug in the 7.1 version of this driver that was related to the specific certificates I was using and I have now successfully tested a private build of version 7.3. Thanks for great support to devart.

Answer (score 0):

Use [nPgSQL](http://npgsql.projects.pgfoundry.org/) with `SSL=True;Sslmode=Require;` to enforce SSL. [The enum doesn't seem to provide `Verify`](http://npgsql.projects.pgfoundry.org/docs/api/Npgsql.SslMode.html), though (like in the JDBC driver) it might always verify unless overridden. I don't have it around to test with.

If you need to you can provide a suitable [`CertificateValidationCallback`](http://npgsql.projects.pgfoundry.org/docs/api/Npgsql.NpgsqlConnection.CertificateValidationCallback.html) to do a certificate verification using C# APIs yourself.

Comment: These are the same options that are available for the devart driver that I am using. I have asked devart to help out and will see what they have to say before I try another driver.

Comment: @vzczc Good thought. Also try testing it with a cert that is valid but has the wrong hostname, see if it actually complains or not.